# Let $|G|=p^7$ and $K\le G$ with $|K|=p^3$. Then $\exists M\le G$ of order $p^4$ such that $K \trianglelefteq M$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

> Let $G$ be a group with order $p^7$ and $K\leq G$ with $|K|=p^3$. Then there exists a subgroup $M$ of $G$ of order $p^4$ such that $K \trianglelefteq M$.

My immediate thought is to consider the normalizer $N_G(K)$. While I can prove that $N_G(K)\neq K$, I cannot assert that it has order $p^4$. I don't need a full solution, just a hint or two.

Thanks!

Comment: The normalizer may have order greater than $p^4$, but any subgroup of the normalizer order $p^4$ that contains $K$ will do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My problem is how to guarantee that there exists such a subgroup.

Comment: Do you know about $p$ groups have non-trivial center?

Comment: I think it's exactly as difficult a question as to prove that, in every $p$-group $G$, if $H<G$ then $H<N_G(H)$.

Comment: Consider $N/K$, where $N$ is the normalizer. Then pull back a subgroup of order $p$ from $N/K$, which will give you a subgroup $H$ of $N$ that contains $K$ and with $[H:K]=p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I got it. Let $N=N_G(K)$. If $N$ has order $p^4$ we are done. Now say it has order $p^5$ and that there is no order $p^4$ subgroup of $N$ that contains $K$. Then $N/K$ would be a simple group of order $p^2$ which is absurd since it is a non-trivial $p$-group so it has nontrivial center. Continuing that way we can take care of the case $|N|=p^6,p^7$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Correct, but too complicated. You don't even need that much. $N/K$ is a finite $p$-group, so it contains a subgroup of order $p$. Its lift is a subgroup $K<H<N$ with $[H:K]=p$, which is exactly what you are looking for. You can do regardless of the size of $N$, since you know that $[N:K]$ is greater than $1$. You don't need to lift a normal subgroup, or a central one, because it is all contained in the normalizer of $K$ anyway.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. That's basically the correspondence theorem, right?

Comment: Cauchy to get the subgroup of order $p$, the correspondence theorem to lift it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Very nice! Thanks again.